# Form (cart) won't work without radio button tag for variant_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I have a Spree application and obviously cart form in it.

[Here](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v3.0.0/frontend/app/views/spree/products/_cart_form.html.erb) is the code for `_cart.html.erb` from Spree(3.0) Github page.(line 9 and 10)

I want to kick out variant option from cart but when I delete radio button tag or label tag and submit it redirect me to the error page: "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

With radio button and label tag it works fine.

My question is: how to get rid of variants from this page?

Server logs:

```
Started POST "/orders/populate" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-03-15 12:08:20 +0100
Processing by Spree::OrdersController#populate as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PgUid1oGjoCYLbu9XR4T40C1ZRTTDTHzjYHq15TDvZNjyBKwKPiYplUF8+AHZyvsZ4PQnEDsGQEW4vXwO1gMsA==", "quantity"=>"1", "button"=>""}
/home/mycomp/RubymineProjects/store/vendor/bundle/gems/versioncake-2.3.1/lib/versioncake/strategies/extraction_strategy.rb:8: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
  Spree::Preference Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "spree_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE "spree_preferences"."key" = ? LIMIT 1  [["key", "spree/frontend_configuration/locale"]]
  Spree::Order Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "spree_orders".* FROM "spree_orders" WHERE "spree_orders"."number" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Spree::Store Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "spree_stores".* FROM "spree_stores" WHERE (url like '%localhost%')  ORDER BY "spree_stores"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Spree::Store Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "spree_stores".* FROM "spree_stores" WHERE "spree_stores"."default" = ?  ORDER BY "spree_stores"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["default", "t"]]
  Spree::Order Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "spree_orders".* FROM "spree_orders" WHERE "spree_orders"."completed_at" IS NULL AND "spree_orders"."currency" = ? AND "spree_orders"."guest_token" = ? AND "spree_orders"."store_id" = ? AND "spree_orders"."user_id" IS NULL LIMIT 1  [["currency", "USD"], ["guest_token", "JlrpVMbX2Xll07oQ3eNp7Q"], ["store_id", 1]]
  Spree::Adjustment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "spree_adjustments".* FROM "spree_adjustments" WHERE "spree_adjustments"."adjustable_type" = 'Spree::Order' AND "spree_adjustments"."adjustable_id" IN (4)  ORDER BY spree_adjustments.created_at ASC
  Rendered public/404.html (2.3ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 175ms (Views: 57.9ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

Comment: What do you have in server logs when submit the form?

Comment: I edited question

Comment: I've not worked with Spree before, but looking at the OrdersController, it appears that even if it doesn't fail in an action callback, it would have failed in the `populate` action when it's not able to find the `Variant`. https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v3.0.0/frontend/app/controllers/spree/orders_controller.rb#L42

Comment: Will making new controller with same name as from Spree(rails engine) github solve the problem if I delete these variants from populate action?

Comment: Like i said earlier, I've not worked with Spree before; so my recommendations are not rules, however I'm guessing what you're really after is presentational, so I'm thinking why not just have the button and label tags as hidden elements? OR just set a default variant then set that as a hidden field for the `variant_id`, so essentially, you'd replace https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v3.0.0/frontend/app/views/spree/products/_cart_form.html.erb#L7-L22 with https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v3.0.0/frontend/app/views/spree/products/_cart_form.html.erb#L26